# Automating Visual Studio 2010 from a console app

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio, visual-studio-2010, automation

I am trying to run the following code (which I got from [here](http://www.knowdotnet.com/articles/outputwindow.html)).  The code just creates a new "Output" pane in Visual Studio and writes a few lines to it.

```
Public Sub WriteToMyNewPane()
    Dim win As Window = _
       dte.Windows.Item(EnvDTE.Constants.vsWindowKindOutput)
    Dim ow As OutputWindow = win.Object
    Dim owPane As OutputWindowPane
    Dim cnt As Integer = ow.OutputWindowPanes.Count
    owPane = ow.OutputWindowPanes.Add("My New Output Pane")
    owPane.Activate()
    owPane.OutputString("My text1" & vbCrLf)
    owPane.OutputString("My text2" & vbCrLf)
    owPane.OutputString("My text3" & vbCrLf)
End Sub
```

Instead of running it as a Macro, I want to run it as an independent console application that connects to a currently running instance of Visual Studio 2010.  I'm having a hard time figuring out how to set the value of **dte**.  I think I may need to call GetActiveObject, but I'm not sure how.  Any pointers?

Comment: This seems like a very unusual requirement. What are you trying to achieve? Assuming it is even possible, how would this work with two or more running instances of VS 2010?

If you really need VS to communicate with an external OS process, consider writing a custom Extension, which interacts with another process using named pipes, WCF, raw sockets, etc.

Comment: @Simon, I think you are misunderstanding... I don't want VS to communicate with another process... I want a console app (a very simple one) to communicate with a currently running instance of VS.  This seems to be a very standard case of automating a running app (in this case the app being Visual Studio)

Comment: The VS<>ConsoleApp communication can be in either direction. I still maintain that using a VS Extension to listen for commands from an other process over (e.g.) WCF would be the way to go. VS extensions have full access to the Visual Studio 2010 SDK, and are written in managed code, not VBScript. Also, you would be able to build in other features into the extension, like security and activity logging.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, this is somewhat possible, the DTE interface supports out-of-process activation.  Here's sample code that shows the approach:

```
Imports EnvDTE

Module Module1
    Sub Main()
        Dim dte As DTE = DirectCast(Interaction.CreateObject("VisualStudio.DTE.10.0"), EnvDTE.DTE)
        dte.SuppressUI = False
        dte.MainWindow.Visible = True
        Dim win As Window = dte.Windows.Item(Constants.vsWindowKindOutput)
        Dim ow As OutputWindow = DirectCast(win.Object, OutputWindow)
        Dim owPane As OutputWindowPane = ow.OutputWindowPanes.Add("My New Output Pane")
        owPane.Activate()
        owPane.OutputString("My text1" & vbCrLf)
        owPane.OutputString("My text2" & vbCrLf)
        owPane.OutputString("My text3" & vbCrLf)
        Console.WriteLine("Press enter to terminate visual studio")
        Console.ReadLine()
    End Sub
End Module
```

The previous to last statement shows why this isn't really practical.  As soon as your program stops running, the last reference count on the coclass disappears, making Visual Studio quit.

Comment: Can I get the currently running instance instead of starting a new one?

Comment: @Joel: What if there are two or more VS instances - how would the above VBScript choose?

Comment: @Joel: you can't, you can only create a new instance.  Standard COM server practice.  Some servers publish a class factory in the ROT, Visual Studio doesn't.

Comment: You can.  See [here](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/vsxprerelease/thread/3e2db97c-1b71-4d3f-b58b-a27089e84446) for a starting point.  If there are multiple instances of VS open, then the running object table will contain multiple objects with monikers that contain "VisualStudio.DTE.10.0".

Comment: As the above link is broken, here is a Powershell 5.1 nothing to install version for Visual Studio 2019   https://github.com/jefflomax/visual-studio-dte-utilities/blob/main/getDteBySolutionName.ps1